# Drawing arrows by dragging mouse

Tags: jquery, css

There are a couple of things I am looking to do with `jquery`. When I click on something, an oval shape is drawn and I could write text into it.

[image]

Holding `enter` or any other key, I drag the mouse to draw an arrow to a point, where another oval shape will lie.

[image]

Is there a library that will let me do this? Or, could any one guide me how doI achieve this.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, perhaps something like this will help: http://www.jointjs.com/

Comment: @HalfCrazed Could you give me an example?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: you can have the look at demos provided .

Comment: @HalfCrazed While using, I get an error on `joint.js` : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined`